# Is there a way to dismiss an no button UIalertView after some time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, dismiss

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"tittle"
               message:@""
                 delegate:self
              cancelButtonTitle:@""
              otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [alertView show];
  [alertView release];
```

i want to dimiss the alerview after it's showing for some time,but when the alertview has no button,it doesn't work if i invoked `-dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated: method`and-`performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`
is there any other way to dismiss it ?
thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
-(void)xx  {
     [self performSelector:@selector(dismissAlertView:) withObject:alertView afterDelay:2];
}
-(void)dismissAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView{
    [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

that's it.i fix it

Comment: Ben, if the cancelButton of the alertView is set to "nil", how will the "[alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];" thing work??? I tried that and it worked, but cant figure out how.... Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use 10 seconds delays to dismiss

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"" message:@"" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(10.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        p\Perform Action after dismiss alertViewController
    }];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In Xamarin.iOS / Monotouch this worked for me:

```
private async Task ShowToast(string message, UIAlertView toast = null)
    {
        if (null == toast)
        {
            toast = new UIAlertView(null, message, null, null, null);
            toast.Show();
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            await ShowToast(message, toast);
            return;
        }

        UIView.BeginAnimations("");
        toast.Alpha = 0;
        UIView.CommitAnimations();
        toast.DismissWithClickedButtonIndex(0, true);
    }
```

Remember that if an async method is called from a background thread (not the main UI thread) then InvokeOnMainThread would still be required.
This just means that you call the above method like this:

```
 BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
 {
   ShowToast(message);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

update to the answer above as `UIAlertView` is `deprecated`
[Answer At this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4192635)

the 2nd function should be like this

```
-(void)dismissAlertView:(UIAlertController *)alertView{

  [alertView dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```